# Modal work But not delete data with clicking confirm

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to delete my data with modal confirmation.on remove click my modal show but when click confirm then data not delete.

I am trying but cant understand whats wrong with my code

my code

```
<script>
$(document).on("click", "#deleteBtn", function (e) {


    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
     var link = $(this).attr('data-adid');



    console.log($("#myModal btn-warning a"));
     $("#myModal .btn-warning a").attr('href',link);
     $(".modal").modal("show");
});
</script>


                    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title">Remove Client Account</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">

                                    Body goes here...

                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Close</button>
                                    <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button"> <a href="" >Confirm</a></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


<a  class="btn btn-warning" id="deleteBtn" data-adid=?a=client&cdid='.$cd[$i][0].' data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal">Remove</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I too can't understand what's wrong with your code, but since you want to delete the data attribute, you can do the below.

```
$(this).removeAttr("data-adid");
```

Comment: i see that when i click then <a href="" >Confirm</a> here no url come but should come ?a=client&cdid='.$cd[$i][0].'